# How to apply my data source to pentaho CCC Pared Bar-Line Measures

Tags: pentaho

Hi guy i'm newbie for Pentaho tool. Now i have some data source look like this

[image]

And i want to apply my data with this chart

[image]

I see a documentation already but I not understand every thing. Can some tell me some tip or solution please. Thank a lot

Comment: You have to learn pentaho BI server first and learn how to design dashboard.

Comment: I'm done on this